# git - reorder commits safely

Tags: git, rebase

I've discovered that reordering commits via `git rebase -i` may not produce the same end result tree when dealing with removed files - and may do so with no warning or error message.

Take the following sequence of commits

```
A - Add foo1
B - Add foo2
C - Remove foo2, Add Foo3
```

Using `git rebase -i` to reorder the commits from A-B-C to A-C-B results in foo2 being present in the HEAD.

Is there a way to reorder commits that barks if the reorder would alter the final resulting tree?

I think `git rebase` is internally using `git am` to apply patches.  I don't see any relevant args to `git am` that could be used to force a fail upon removal of a non-existent file, which is what I think would be needed.  Do I have to patch the git source code to get what I want?

Comment: *"I think git rebase is internally using git am to apply patches."*

I don't think so... I believe git uses the history information when rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

did you make the contents of the files differ by a lot? It can be seen as a move if they are too similar. You should get stopped with a conflict when you try and apply a patch to remove a file that's not there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not really the issue.  All 3 files are in the A-C-B tree after the rebase -i.  try it.  (the files i used were all empty)

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase, compare the result, and then possibly reset to the old state. A simple combination of

- `git stash save --include-untracked` to get into a clean state
- `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the hash of the current commit
- `git rebase` to do the real work
- `git checkout the_previously_saved_hash .` to restore the state before rebasing
- `git clean -fd` to get rid of all superfluous files
- `git commit -m "Undoing the changes introduces by rebase."` which may fail if the rebase introduced no changes (this failure can be silently ignored)
- `git stash pop` to re-introduce the stashed-away "pollution"

should do... I guess I'll try to make a script like this soon as it's something I need as well.